# Stripe Charge Date Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Again, I am new to stripe. I am using Rails and no JS for this section and I want to display the time a charge was made to the customer in my app. [In the charge JSON](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#retrieve_charge), I see this: `"created": 1461761985,`.

So in my loop, **(shortened)**:

```
...
 <%= c.created.strftime() %>
...
```

> undefined method `strftime' for 1461761985:Fixnum

I thought I could use [strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime) but getting few errors. Is there a way of converting this time format to `D-M-Y`, in Rails 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a unix timestamp if I'm not wrong. Try these out:

```
DateTime.strptime(c.created.to_s, '%s')
# or
Time.at(c.created).to_datetime
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have settle with: `<%= Time.at(c.created).to_datetime.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %>`